# Using Browser Router in react-router-dom with Django backend

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router

I'm building an application that uses React as front-end and Django Rest as back-end.
From front-end, I'm using react-router-dom for declarative routing and Django only serves API

So when user enters an URL like this `https://myapp.com/something/something-else`, it's actually handle by Django and it will return an error since Django doesn't know which page to lead to with this URL. It should be handled by React instead.

One of the workaround I have is to use a Hash Router, so the URL will look like this (with the hash symbol): `https://myapp.com/#/something/something-else`

But there have been cases where user will just key the URL without the hash sign (as they didn't know).

Is there away to handle this without using Hash Router?

Comment: What is the reason behind Django serving URLs that are in react scope

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly because you haven't provided code, or an explanation of your project structure.

How are you doing a hash-router? If you have Django serving a single HTML file, then you should be able to edit your `urls.py` to pass any URLs that don't match the api to the same page.

As an example, I have a Django website with a Preact frontend, and I have Preact files that are built into static .js files, which are then served by Apache. Django does all URL routing and serves HTML files, which then request the Preact JS files from Apache.